# what is program alignment error flag (PGAERR) in stm32f407?

Tags: embedded, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to implement my own drivers for [stm32f407](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) from bare-metal, my problem is that I don't understand what the term `program alignment error flag (PGAERR)` means, as in page 87 from `Embedded Flash Memory Section`, it says:

> It is not allowed to program data to the Flash memory that would cross
> the 128-bit row  boundary. In such a case, the write operation is not
> performed and a program alignment  error flag (PGAERR) is set in the
> FLASH_SR register.

I tried to look for any other definitions from the reference manual, so I look into bit definitions of registers and I found:

[image]

from my understanding, it means we can't write more than 128-bit at the same time to flash memory but at the same time, there is no data type greater than 64-bit in `C` as in `uint64_t` so I assume my assumption is wrong, so is there any example cases that can illustrate when will this error flag be 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the memory into 128-bit chunks (in your mind). If you perform a 64-bit write, you can't have half of it in one 128-bit chunk, and another half (or part) of it in another 128-bit chunk. The entire piece of data must be entirely in one 128-bit chunk.

```
|______________ 128-bit ___________ || ___________ 128-bit _____________ ||
| 32-bit | 32-bit | 32-bit | 32-bit || 32-bit | 32-bit | 32-bit | 32-bit ||
↑                          ↑
Writing 64-bit here is ok  Writing 64-bit here is >not< ok
```